# unable to change text size

Tags: html, css

I have an image and I put some text next to it by making the text  `span` but I can't seem to change the font size. I tried changing it from a number of different places inside css with no luck.

```css
body {
  border: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: serif, sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  position: static;
  height: 90px;
}

img {
  font-size: 16;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Audi</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <img class="logo" src="https://cdn.freelogovectors.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/audi-logo.png" alt="logo">
  <hr>

  <img style="height: 400px;" src="https://www.autozone-mag.com/uploads/1666-audi-rs-6-avant-2019.jpg" alt="RS6">
  <span>this is some text</span>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You set the font-size to the `<img>`, not to the `<span>`.

Comment: `font-size: 16;` is not a valid declaration. You must specify a unit, like in `16px`, or `16pt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
span {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```css
span {
  font-size: 30px;
}

body {
  border: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: serif, sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  position: static;
  height: 90px;
}

img {
  font-size: 16;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Audi</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <img class="logo" src="https://cdn.freelogovectors.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/audi-logo.png" alt="logo">
  <hr>

  <img style="height: 400px;" src="https://www.autozone-mag.com/uploads/1666-audi-rs-6-avant-2019.jpg" alt="RS6">
  <span>this is some text</span>


</body>

</html>
```

Or perhaps add a class:

```
.text-beside-car-image {
   font-size: 30px;
}
```

```css
.text-beside-car-image {
  font-size: 30px;
}

body {
  border: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: serif, sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  position: static;
  height: 90px;
}

img {
  font-size: 16;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Audi</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <img class="logo" src="https://cdn.freelogovectors.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/audi-logo.png" alt="logo">
  <hr>

  <img style="height: 400px;" src="https://www.autozone-mag.com/uploads/1666-audi-rs-6-avant-2019.jpg" alt="RS6">
  <span class="text-beside-car-image">this is some text</span>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please excuse the redundant answer. I was typing when you posted yours.. thank you!

Comment: @lanpierre Your answer provides many details that I left out. Great contribution! Bless.

Answer (score 2):

You are targeting the `img` HTML tag, not the `span` HTML tag.

Your CSS rule (below) does not apply to the text because the rule targets `img` but the text is in a `span` tag.

```
img {
  font-size: 16;
  /* ... */
}
```

Furthermore, `font-size: 16` is missing a unit type, such as `px`, `pt`, `em`, `rem`, etc. (see [CSS Units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)).

Finally, please let me know if a detailed example would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set font-size in the element span, not in the element img. Because the element img doesn't support font-size attribute. Thus, you can set

```
span {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Also, when you put unit in the CSS, you need to put Absolute Units (`px, pt` etc...) or Relative Units (`em, rem` etc...). Not only the number like that, because it's not interpreted from browser.

```
img {
  font-size: 16;      
}
```

e.g. `font-size: 16px;`

Finally, you don't see any different if you set `font-size: 16px;` because the **browser default font size** is `16px`. To see a difference you need to put `font size > 16px` or `font size < 16px`.

```css
body {
  border: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: serif, sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  position: static;
  height: 90px;
}

img {  
  vertical-align: top;
}

span {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Audi</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <img class="logo" src="https://cdn.freelogovectors.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/audi-logo.png" alt="logo">
  <hr>

  <img style="height: 400px;" src="https://www.autozone-mag.com/uploads/1666-audi-rs-6-avant-2019.jpg" alt="RS6">
  <span>this is some text</span>


</body>

</html>
```